# ajax in html, get result from php

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I have html:

```
<body>
<div class="po-logo">
  <img src="img/logos/lw.png" alt="logo watchbees"/>
</div>
<form>
<div class="mui-textfield mui-textfield--float-label reg-window">
  <input id="username" name="username" type="text"/>
  <label>Username</label>
</div>
<div class="mui-textfield mui-textfield--float-label reg-window">
  <input id="password" name="password" type="password"/>
  <label>Password</label>
</div>
<div class="mui-textfield mui-textfield--float-label reg-window">
  <button id="login" value="submit" onclick="return result" class="mui-btn mui-btn--raised reg-win-button">Sign in</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Jquery in html:

```
$("#login").click(function(){
      var username=$("#username").val();
      var password=$("#password").val();
      if(($.trim(username).length > 0) & ($.trim(password).length > 0))
      {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://127.0.0.1/app/login.php",
        data: {username: username, password: password},
        beforeSend: function(){ $("#login").html('Prihlasovanie...');},
        success: function(data){
        if(data == "success")
        {
          localStorage.login="true";
          localStorage.username=username;
          window.location.href = "profil.html";
          }
        else if (data = "failed")
        {
          alert("Problem s prihlasením, skúste znovu.");
          $("#login").html('Prihlásiť sa');
          }
          }
        });
      }return false;
    });
```

And php file on localserver, login.php:

```
if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])){
$username=mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['username'])));
$password=mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['password'])));
$login = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE `username`='$username' AND `password`='$password'"));
if($login != 0){
echo "success";
}
else{
echo "failed";
}
}
```

But something is wrong, ajax doesn't send my back any data. It only changes #login to "connecting..."  but nothing happens. Inscribing information is correct and they are uploaded to the database. Most likely php doesn't send back any data or ajax in html doesn't correct processing data from php. I don't where is problem. Profil.html is in the same folder as index.html. But login.php is on local server.

HTML: index.html; PHP: login.php on local server on my latop; Server: 127.0.0.1, database name db_login.

Any help or pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors? Or at least checked if the request is being sent, and what the response is?

Comment: Then your AJAX request isn't being sent, which implies your click handler is not being hit. Are you running your code when the DOM is ready?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1/app/login.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: There's your problem. Google that will provide you with plenty of solutions

Comment: Thank you Rory,  have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

First - you have to check is ajax request pointed correctly to your php file. Open inspector in Chrome, switch to tan network then Emanuel filter xhr. After click on #login you should see new request there. Click on it, switch to response tab and paste its content here Please

Comment: There is nothing, writes only "This request has no response data available". But why... I don't know

Comment: Are you Sure that request points to php file correctly ? Did you receive response status 200? Try to echo "something"; exit(); in very first line of that file, then check out response

Comment: status code is 200, but response data is "<br /> <b>Warning</b>: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\app\login.php</b> on line <b>11</b><br /> failed"

Comment: Its your problem. As far as I see on small display of my iPhone from js you pasa parameter username but in php you use variable login (instead of username).  That error inform you your sql query is wrong (mysql_num_rows() get boolean false as argument) :) lets debug that query and you will find your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is below lines:

in JS:

```
data: {username: username, password: password},
```

in PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
```

**Reason**

From JS side, you are passing 2 params in the `POST` request: `username` and `password`, while in PHP, you are checking for `$_POST['login']`. You should instead be checking for `$_POST['username']` and `$_POST['password']` in PHP.

Also, you are using `mysql_real_escape_string()` which is deprecated since PHP 5.5. And, you are injecting the username and password, which are both user inputs, directly into the mysql query leading to serious security issues relating to SQL Injection. Use [PHP-MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) API and prepared statements.

Comment: I use your issue but inspector - network - xhr write this error "<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\app\login.php</b> on line <b>11</b><br />
failed"

Comment: That means your sql is not correct after injecting the values. Use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

OK, but why first If takes true ? Author, Please give us request headers of that xhr from inspector

Comment: This is
`POST /app/login.php HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 32
Accept: */*
Origin: null
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.28
Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: sk-SK,sk;q=0.8,cs;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.4,en;q=0.2`

Comment: You miss request parameters :) Please paste it here (maximum down at request tab)

Comment: you mean form data? because maximum down at reguest tab is only form data: "username=name&password=123456"
http://imgur.com/a/88j4G

Comment: Exactly. Did you tried to change in php use variable login to username ?

Comment: Sorry. Its best now to separate query to php variable, echo that variable (query) and paste it directly to some mysql client do run in directly in mysql. Parser will give you more details about query issue